# ng12 update instructions yield broken app

Tags: angular-cli

I went to upgrade an ng11 app to ng 12, as instructed by [update.angular.io](https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=11.0-12.0).
Upgrading /core and /cli as mentioned on the page resulted in other packages (such as /router) not upgraded and incompatible.

Is this the complete procedure? Should I also `npm update @angular/router` and all other packages "by hand"?

Below is my package.json after running `ng update @angular/core@12 @angular/cli@12`. As you see, Typescript has not been updated to 4.2 as promised by the instructions.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~11.2.14",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1102.13",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~11.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: `yarn ng update @angular/core @angular/cli`. Make sure you are using `ng` from `node_modules/.bin/ng`. This should update all angular packages and run code migrations

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work. I was receiving contradictory messages like: angular/core up to date, and below an instruction to update core from 11.x.x to 12.2.7. Again I hit the darkest side of angular. Luckily the project is small enough to just paste package.json from a fresh ng new installation.